# UserStoreException when connecting wso2 is to oracle

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Dears, I tried https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#step-1-download-and-install-wso2-is to use oracle db as shared_db between wso2 api manager and identity server and got this error ? just created databases and set deployment config based on the document.

```
nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: can you check this[1] whether you have the same issue? (hope you have added drivers properly). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393719/wso2-is-org-wso2-carbon-user-core-userstoreexception-null

Comment: can u share the full error log (be mindful about any sensitive info when sharing the log)?

Comment: Thanks Sominda, It was region problem in windows server and impropriate version of jdbc, I don't know why but it solved, After integrating Api manager and Identity server, I can no see created users that I create in Identity server in Api manager or even database, I just connect both Identity server and api manager to shared db.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058383/). Check the provided answer.

Seems like changing the region might resolve the issue (if you have configured all others properly including the compatible drivers).